# DOMDocument change when webframe loadrequest

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

In my webkit plugin, I can get DOMDocument from [webFrame DOMDocument] in the first time load the web that embed my plugin.

```
 webFrame = [[arguments objectForKey:WebPlugInContainerKey] webFrame];

   DOMDocument *dom = [webFrame DOMDocument];
```

But when the webframe load another url (that not embed my plugin)

```
 [webFrame loadRequest: myRequest];

   DOMDocument *dom1 = [webFrame DOMDocument];
```

it is error to access dom1!!
I do not know which method to access DOMDocument with the webframe that loaded myRequest??
any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

you have to wait for the download to complete before calling domDocument by using a the delegate